# how to add a background sound in my program that does not stop until I close the console in c++

Tags: c++, windows

The issue I'm facing is that the sound is not running in a loop, the whole sound is executed once, it does not repeat.

So basically, I have used this method:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void play_music() {
    PlaySoundA("sound.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_LOOP);
}

int main(){
    
 std::thread t(play_music); 
 //code
 t.join();
}
```

Comment: If this flag is set, you must also set the SND_ASYNC flag. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)

Comment: Does PlaySound return after playing the whole file or it's "async"? If it returns after playing you could just call the `play_music()` function after `PlaySoundA()`.

Comment: I want it to run in a loop until I close the console or the program is terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **SND_LOOP**
>
> The sound plays repeatedly until PlaySound is called again with the pszSound parameter set to NULL. **If this flag is set, you must also set the SND_ASYNC flag.**

Answer (score 0):

The `SND_LOOP` flag requires the `SND_ASYNC` flag, which means `PlaySoundA()` will exit immediately, and thus your thread will terminate, which will cause `join()` to exit, allowing `main()` to exit.

If you want to play the sound in a *synchronous* loop, then remove the `SND_LOOP` flag and call `PlaySoundA()` in a loop instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_bool keep_playing{ true };

void play_music() {
    while (keep_playing.load()) {
        PlaySoundA("sound.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    }
}

int main(){  
  std::thread t(play_music); 
  //code
  keep_playing.store(false);
  t.join();
}
```

But in this case, you don't actually need the thread at all, just let `SND_ASYNC` to its job, eg:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){  
  PlaySoundA("sound.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);
  //code
  PlaySoundA(NULL, NULL, 0);
}
```